# How to create a waveform using custom painter - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter

In the below code i need to show the wave form when the user speaks, but i'm not sure about the code, it does't gets me positive

Reference image [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5odR.png)

Also it needs to be varies based on the amplitude change and color of the wave also to be changed based on the resultant amplitude

```
///
class Waveform extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<double> amplitudes;

  const Waveform(this.amplitudes, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 100.0,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: WaveformPainter(amplitudes),
      ),
    );
  }
}

///
class WaveformPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<double> amplitudes;

  WaveformPainter(this.amplitudes);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 4.0;

    final Path path = Path();

    for (int i = 0; i < amplitudes.length; i++) {
      final double x = i * size.width / (amplitudes.length - 1);
      final double y = (1 - amplitudes[i]) * size.height / 2;

      if (i == 0) {
        path.moveTo(x, y);
      } else {
        path.lineTo(x, y);
      }
    }

    // Adding gradient
    paint.shader = LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
        Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5),
        Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.0),
      ],
    ).createShader(Rect.fromPoints(Offset(0, 0), Offset(0, size.height)));

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks good but I assume it results in sharp lines instead of smooth curves at peaks. One way to achieve the smooth wave is by using the [CatmullRomSpline](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/CatmullRomSpline-class.html). For this, you will need at least 4 values in your input list of amplitues. If you don't have 4 points you will have to generate them.

```dart
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  // normalize amplitude values based on the size
  final points = normalize(amplitudes, size);
  // ensure that at least 4 points are available;
  final spline = CatmullRomSpline(points);
  final samples = spline.generateSamples().toList();
  final path = Path();
  final startOffset = samples.first.value;
  path.moveTo(startOffset.dx, startOffset.dy);

  for (final sample in samples) {
    path.lineTo(sample.value.dx, sample.value.dy);
  }

  final paint = /* config your paint */;
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```